# How to find words in a list that contain the same first letter python

Tags: python, list

Write a function `common_start(word_list)` that takes in parameter a list of words.
This function must return a new list containing all words that start with the same letter as at least one other word in the list.

**input**: ['file', 'edit', 'view', 'insert', 'format']
**output**: ['file', 'format']

Comment: input: ['times', 'consolas', 'courier', 'arial', 'cambria', 'trebuchet', 'wingdings'])
output:['times', 'consolas', 'courier', 'cambria', 'trebuchet']

Answer (score 1):

A one line solution, if you want

```
def common_start(input_list):
    return [word for word in input_list if sum([w.startswith(word[0]) for w in input_list]) > 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you.
In this case I'm ignoring the duplicated words.

```
def common_start(word_list):
    output = set()

    for word in word_list:
        for first_letter in word_list:
            if word == first_letter:
                next
            elif word[0] == first_letter[0]:
                output.add(word)
    return list(output)
```

Input:  ['tara', 'file', 'edit', 'view', 'insert', 'format','test']

Output: ['tara', 'file', 'format', 'test']